# Show that $x^2 + x + [1]$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]$

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Assuming $x^2 + x + [1]$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]$

$$x^2 + x + [1] = (x + [a])(x + [b]) = x^2 + [a]x + [b]x + [a][b] = x^2 + ([a]+[b])x + [a][b]$$

for some $[a],[b] \in \mathbb{Z}_2$

This means that

$$[a]+[b] = [a+b] = [1] \therefore[a]=[1]-[b]=[1-b]$$
$$[a][b]=[ab]=[1] \therefore [a]=[b]^{-1}$$

Putting these two equations together,

$$[b-1] = [b]^{-1}$$

Inspecting the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$

$$[1] = [-1] = [0-1] \neq [0]^{-1}=[0]$$
$$[0]=[1-1] \neq [1]^{-1}=[1]$$

$\square$

Comment: A degree 2 or 3 polynomial is reducible iff they have a root in underlying field.( One factor must be linear )

Comment: $[0]^{-1} = [0]$ is not correct. The zero element is not invertible.

Comment: Oh ok! @azimut. Can I use that argument to prove irreducibility this way?

Comment: @TheBosco Yes, you can fix that. The standard way to show irreducibility in this case is indicated by Panchal Schamsundar. Just plug in [0] and [1] into your polynomial to see that neither is a root. This implies that your polynomial is not divisible by a linear factor. Together with degree 2, this implies irreducibility.